# Unordered_set trouble

Tags: c++, unordered-set

I need help with my program that  works like this: First the number of data sets is served at input.
then the size of each set is indicated.

My task is to write each of the numbers, but without repetitions in the order they were entered. For example we have three numbers 2, 10, 2. So the answer should be: 2, 10.

My problem is that the unordered_set sometimes somehow sort these numbers and sometimes not. I cant work out why its happening.

This is my work:

```
`#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include<unordered_set>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int t,n,l;
    unordered_set<int> Uniq;
    unordered_set<int>::iterator it;
    vector<int> new_line;
    vector<int>Answer;
    cin >> t;
    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++)
    {
        cin >> n;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            cin >> l;
            Uniq.insert(l);
        }
        for (it = Uniq.begin(); it != Uniq.end(); it++)
        {
            Answer.push_back(*it);
        }
        new_line.push_back(Uniq.size());
        Uniq.clear();
    }
    int g = 0,h=1;
    for (int i = 0; i < Answer.size(); i++)
    {
        if (h == new_line[g])
        {
            h = 1;
            g++;
            cout << Answer[i] << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << Answer[i] << " ";
            h++;
        }
    }
}`
```

I tried many things and none of them helped. Im a student and its my first  time using unordered_set or even normal set.

Comment: _"... My problem is that the unordered_set sometimes somehow sort these numbers and sometimes not..."_ `std::unordered_set` does not guarantee any ordering (clue is in the name).  If you want an ordered set use [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) _"...Sorting is done using the key comparison function..."_

Comment: I would like these numbers to be listed in the order they were entered

Comment: @AwangardowyEkstrawagant12 Did you try the suggestion I gave in my answer? If you want me to explain anything in more detail, just ask in the comment section under the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a combination of a `vector` and an `unordered_set`. Use the `vector` to store the numbers in the order you enter them and use the `unordered_set` to keep track of numbers already entered. Example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    int t;
    if (not(std::cin >> t) || t < 1) return 1;

    std::unordered_set<int> Uniq;
    std::vector<int> Answer;
    int n;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        if (not(std::cin >> n)) return 1;

        auto [it, inserted] = Uniq.insert(n);

        // only store `n` if it was inserted in the `unordered_set`.
        // (duplicates will not be inserted):
        if (inserted) Answer.push_back(n);
    }

    for (int value : Answer) {
        std::cout << value << '\n';
    }
}
```